# How do I make it so these div elements don't overlap?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I made a website with div's, classes and everything a website needs. But when I resize the window all the inner text moves over the NavArea and Buttons overlap. Like even on StackOverflow the top of the page has the search text box and when I resize the window it just moves overtop. What's the solution to this? Here is the code--

CSS:  http://pastebin.com/2rqinFJw

HTML: http://pastebin.com/u7eXUkwC

Please test the code before you post an answer please, I have tried everything and need an indepth answer that I can understand. I have spent way too long but do not plan to give up!

Answer (score 4):

Ok!

So firstly, a main problem with your programming (as I see it) is that you're using absolute positioning **way too often** - like honestly, they should nearly never be used for creating a website layout.

Also, this part of your code:

```
<div id="b1">
<ul>
<a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="b2">
<ul>
<a href="index.html"><li>Downloads</li></a>
</ul>
</div>
```

No offense, this isn't the correct layout for a navigation bar. Your `<a>` tags should go inside your `<li>` tags, not outside! Also, you split your navigation up into two - this is completely unnecessary, while also using `position: absolute;` on a navigation bar - no need at all.

Here's what it should (or could) be:

```
<div id="b1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">Downloads</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note how I've placed the two in the same `<ul>` tag, and also put the `<a>` tags inside of the `<li>` tags. I've also rearranged your CSS to do the same thing.

Not sure what your `<div class="imageArea"></div>` does, but I just threw it in there - it appears you got no CSS code for it anyways.

What I did to the main layout, was I moved it into a `<div class="container">`, which I used the following CSS on:

```
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

This will create a container of sorts that fits in the middle of your screen. You can adjust this width if you want - I just find that `1000px` suits my needs rather well.

Also, I've floated both elements to the left of this - this allows the two `<div>` tags - your navigation section and your `textBody`, to go next to each other. I made them with a width of `20%` and `80%`.

Since I need some spacing in the middle, I added `padding-right: 10px;` to your navigation. Since this makes a total width of `100% + 10px` (which would push the `textBody` down), I added `box-sizing: border;box;` in order for the padding to be counted into the width (so that it makes a total width still `100%`).

Here's the final HTML and CSS:

http://pastebin.com/ZC2TFir2 (HTML)

http://pastebin.com/wEwzRP66 (CSS)

I don't think many will give you an answer as detailed as this (I know I normally wouldn't) - but in all honesty, I believe this webpage could be designed a lot better (plus I'm bored and work hasn't started yet).

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! You just relieved alot of stress and frustration

Comment: +1 not only for the correct answer - also for adding the comment 'don't worry - I'm cooking up an answer for you right now. ;)' to the question.

Comment: @DominikAngerer Haha - I removed the comment after answering the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Positioning everything absolutely is not a good practice. [Absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) will allow elements to move on top of one another. Absolute positioned elements don't care about the layout of other elements.

If you want a nav bar to float to the left of the text, use the [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) property, like so:

```
#nav {
    float: left;
}
```

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bex5b0by/

Answer (score 0):

You could just put in

```
 #nav {
 position: relative ;}

 And after position:relative put in margin-left: -200px or whatever you want it to be. (You can use margin-left/right/top/whatever you need OR left/top/right/etc. : -number px / number px;
```

That means you place your div in relation to the other divs. But for this to happen you have to have the divs in one another. (< BIG div>